# AUTOSYS: Command to fetch job status for multiple jobs at the same time

Tags: scheduler, autosys, broadcom

I don't have access privileges in UNIX for Autosys to fetch the job report by executing commands. Because, when I execute autorep command it's throwing an error which is a command not found
So, I tried using the GUI method where there is an Enterprise Command Line option, but over there I could fetch a job status for one job (or) box at a time and the command which I used was

**autorep -j JOB1**

```
As because I need to fetch reports for multiple jobs, it will be more time-consuming work and a lot of manual work will be involved if I follow the above-mentioned approach.
```

And my query is, What I need to do to fetch the job report for multiple jobs (or) boxes at the same time? Because I tried using the below commands which are

**autorep -j JOB1, JOB2**

**autorep -j JOB1 JOB2**

**autorep -j JOB1 & autorep -j JOB2**

But, nothing didn't work so, can anyone please tell the solution of it?

Answer (score 1):

To enable access to Autosys from linux, you would need to install the Autosys binary and configure a few variables.

From GUI, just to help out with a few queries:

```
autorep -J ALL -s
```

Returns the current job status report of all the jobs in the particular instance.

```
autorep -j APP_ID-APP_NAME* -s
```

You can use globbing patterns unlike in linux.

```
autorep -M Machine-Name -s
```

Returns the current job status report of all the jobs in the particular machine/host/server.

Refer more at [AUTOSYS WORKLOAD AUTOMATION 12.0.01](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/intelligent-automation/autosys-workload-automation/12-0-01/reference/ae-commands/monitor-and-report-on-workload/autorep-command-report-job-machine-and-variable-information.html)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, but I need to fetch reports for only a few jobs like job1 job2 & job3 and not for all the jobs. So, what would be the best solution

Comment: If you say your job names are job1 job2 & job3.  Then "autorep -J job* -s".

Comment: Highly doubtful, but give it a try ## autorep -J ALL -s | grep -E "job1|job2|job3" ##

Comment: Yeah, again there is a blocker that the job name differs like job1 job2 jb3 jb4. If I mention it as a job* then it won't pick a job named jb3 & jb4 right

Comment: autorep -J ALL -s | grep -E "job1|job2" didn't work. Can you please say any other command

Answer (score 1):

you can do that using in 3 ways :

1. Use WCC ( GUI ) " Quick View" and search jobs by giving a comma .
   i.e **job1,job2,job3,......job-n** . This will give you the status of all jobs you need over there but it wont give you a report as such ( copy and paste in bulk and filter out in excel ).
2. If you need report of those jobs then I would do like this :
   Autosys version - 11.3.6 SP8.
   **write a script as follows** :
   **report.bat**

   echo off
   cls
   set mydir="user directory, complete path"
   set input_dir=D:\test\scripts\test
   for /f "tokens=1 delims=|" %%A in (%input_dir%\test_jobs.txt) do (autorep -j -w -10 %%A  | findstr -V "^$ Job Name ______" )

**test_jobs.txt:**

job1
job2
job3
.
.
job-n

above will give the result of jobs as expected, If you want to save the output in a text file and view it  use ">" at the end and export the same to a text file .

3. If you access to IDash Tool then login to IDash and generate a report in reports section based on your requirement . (Easy to use and many report formats are available to download )

**Note:** 1 Use Autosys command line instead of server command line if you prefer script ( search for command line) .

Hope it helps !